# Allow only unique combination of values for a composite primary key

Tags: mysql, mariadb, unique-constraint, mariadb-10.2

I created the following table called `books`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books` (
`id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I created another tablet called compare to compare any 2 books from the `books` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `compare` (
`id_1` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`id_2` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id_1`,`id_2`),
FOREIGN KEY (`id_1`) REFERENCES books(`id`),
FOREIGN KEY (`id_2`) REFERENCES books(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The previous works as expected but I need to force MySQL to allow ONLY unique combination of values in the `compare` table.

For example if I have the following row in `compare` table:

```
id_1 | id_2
------------
  1  |  2
```

I want to force MySQL to NOT allow me to insert the following row:

```
id_1 | id_2
------------
  2  |  1
```

So I want MySQL to allow only either `1,2` or `2,1` NOT both.

I am using 10.2.14-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

Answer (score 9):

Since you use MariaDB 10.2, you can add a `CHECK` constraint, enforcing that the first id is less than the second (`id_1 < id_2`). [`CHECK` constraints](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/constraint/) were added in version 10.2.1.

This has the limitation that you'll have to provide the ids for the `INSERT` statements in correct order (you won't be able to insert the `(3,2)` combination, even if `(2,3)` is not there):

```
ALTER TABLE compare
  ADD CONSTRAINT ids_unique_combination_chk
    CHECK (id_1 < id_2) ;
```

Tested at [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=618efea4cf18dcb65e6878c6c6c5ae77).

---

If you don't want to have to hassle with your `INSERT` statements and procedures, you can use two [`VIRTUAL` (or `PERSISTENT`) columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/generated-columns/) and a `UNIQUE` constraint.

Virtual columns are available in MariaDB since version 5.2 and several limitations were lifted in 10.2.1:

```
ALTER TABLE compare
  ADD small_id BIGINT AS (LEAST(id_1, id_2)) VIRTUAL,
  ADD big_id   BIGINT AS (GREATEST(id_1, id_2)) VIRTUAL,
  ADD CONSTRAINT ids_unique_combination_uq
    UNIQUE (small_id, big_id);
```

Tested at dbfiddle.uk, too: [fiddle-2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=4e60c02ad9a09b6f0c27e50630aa8b69).

Comment: The trick can be done in older versions -- but you have conditionally swap the values in your app.